# How does vpython 7 do a file dialog

Tags: vpython

I'm trying to upgrade an old vpython 5 script to vpython 7.  In this script I import visual.filedialog but I can't find filedialog in the vpython 7's vpython module.  What is the equivalent of filedialog in vpython 7?
Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some VPython documentation on files.

http://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/files.html

It says "he following information does not apply to VPython 7, where one can use the standard Python methods for importing modules and reading or writing files."